# Connecting aws mongo database from localhost?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect to the aws mongodb database from the localhost by configuring robomongo but it is responding as **unable to connect** each time.
when i am checking that mongodb is running on aws

```
service mongod status
```

then is it showing

```
mongod start/running, process 20934
```

Is this correct way of checking whether mongodb is running or not ?
i am adding two ports in security inbound for mongodb **27017** and **28017**

for mongodb and in **Robomongo**  i am providing
name aws

address -amazon ec2 address of instance

port 27017

can anybody tell what is wrong in this process?

Comment: At a guess I would say its a firewall issue blocking connections. Can you confirm that your OS does not have a firewall that is blocking connections (try service iptables status). Have you tried temporarily allowing all traffic through the security group from you IP address? Are you able to connect to the mongodb from the amazon instance where the service is running?

Comment: Also try to do `telnet <amazon-host> 27017` to check connection to aws.

Comment: You should check security groups and public/private IP of the mongodb server. The server might be in a private network or port is not open.

Comment: I think that mongo listens only on localhost by default. You need to use --bind_ip. Have a look at this docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-network/

Comment: I just solved this with openshift. Don't know AWS very well. But might be a similar solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937519/how-do-i-develop-node-js-on-localhost-whilst-connecting-to-remote-mongo-db/42939550#42939550