# How do I develop node js on localhost whilst connecting to remote mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost, openshift, portforwarding

I'm using OpenShift with node js and mongo db.

I'd like to develop updates locally and then push them to the server.

How can I develop node js locally and connect to a remote mongo db.

I've tried port forwarding. This forwards everything for some reason so runs node js server instance. Which is no good. I want to run the localhost node js.

```
rhc port-forward appname
```

This port forwads just mongodb, but if I then run node js in a separate terminal, it's unable to connect.

```
rhc port-forward appname -s mongodb
```

Do i even need port forwarding, or will the correct mongo db connection string solve this?

Hope somebody clever out there knows the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're needing to port forward for. You should be able to connect directly to the mongo server from your local, assuming it's not blocked by a firewall at the server.

Comment: Port forwarding seemed to be the recommended way. I've tried the same connection string used online locally. I'll check the firewall.

Comment: you would need the server's public ip address (or a dns name that points to said public address)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not winning. ok, firewall is off, connection string from localhost nodejs is like this mongodb://admin:ABCDEFGHIJ@nodeapp-name.rhcloud.com/databasename - no joy with any combination I can think of.

Comment: Nope, just times out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved this.

First enable port forwarding for just mongo db.

```
rhc port-forward appname -s mongodb
```

Use a local db connection string

```
mongodb://admin:ABCDEFGHIJ@127.0.0.1:27017/database‌​name
```

Run node

```
node server.js
```

Port forwarding will forward just mongo db via localhost to it's remote location.